# PHP: поиск в массиве объектов

Tags: php, массивы, json, веб-программирование, qiwi

Добрый день. Получаю историю транзакций QIWI-кошелька по API. В ответ приходит [массив объектов](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/#payments_history) в формате JSON:

```
{"data":
  [{
  "txnId":9309,
  "personId":79112223344,
  ...
  "sum":{
    "amount":70,
    "currency":"RUB"
    },
  "source": {},
  "comment":"Test comment #1",
  ...
  }],
  "nextTxnId":9001,
  "nextTxnDate":"2017-01-31T15:24:10+03:00"
}
```

Полученный результат записываю в переменную `$result` и далее завожу 2 переменные:

```
$searchComment = "Test comment #1";
$checkComment = false;
```

Каким образом (желательно на PHP) можно проверить, содержится ли в массиве объектов строка `$searchComment` и, если содержится, то присвоить переменной `$checkComment` значение true? Если потребуется дополнительная информация, без проблем предоставлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При декодировании json используйте второй параметр, который поможет преобразовать объект в массив. Далее извлеките все комменты с помощью `array_column`. После чего используйте `array_search` для поиска значения. В случае успеха будет возвращен индекс элемента. Если же элемент не найден, будет возвращено `false`.

```
$json = '{"data":[{"txnId":9309,"personId":79112223344,"sum":{"amount":70,"currency":"RUB"},"comment":"Test comment #1"}],"nextTxnId":9001,"nextTxnDate":"2017-01-31T15:24:10+03:00"}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);
$comments = array_column($data['data'], 'comment');

$searchComment = "Test comment #1";
$checkComment = array_search($searchComment, $comments) !== false;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию и пример кода. Вы не могли бы пояснить, что означает последняя строка? Она похожа на тернарный оператор, только без знаков "?" и ":". Это какой-то особенный оператор PHP?

Comment: @Win_D [сравнение с проверкой типа](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php), если поиск вернет 0й индекс, то `0 == false` будет истинным выражением, а вот `0 === false` ложным.

Answer (score 1):

К ответу @teran я бы добавил, что можно использовать не array_search, а in_array.

Функция возвращает true или false в зависимости от результата поиска.

Тогда последняя строка была бы чуть короче:

```
$checkComment = in_array($searchComment, $comments);
```